# Greasemonkey code not deleting nodes (or not even executing)

Tags: javascript, html

This is the HTML structure that i want to delete (code pulled from twitch.tv)

```
<div class="stream item" style="width: 300px;">
  <div class="thumb js-var-height" style="height: 148px;">
    <a href="/nicegametv" data-bindattr-491="491" data-ember-action="492" class="cap" data-channel-link="data-channel-link">
      <img src="http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_nicegametv-320x200.jpg" data-bindattr-493="493">
    </a>
    <script id="metamorph-360-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script><a original-title="League of Legends" href="/directory/game/League%20of%20Legends" data-href="/directory/game/League%20of%20Legends" data-bindattr-494="494" data-ember-action="495" class="boxart">
      <img src="http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/League%20of%20Legends-138x190.jpg" data-placeholder="http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/League%20of%20Legends-138x190.jpg" data-bindattr-496="496">
    </a><script id="metamorph-360-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
  </div>
  <div class="meta">
    <p class="title">
      <script id="metamorph-361-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script><a href="/nicegametv" title="SKT T1 K vs Najin sword NLB Final" data-bindattr-497="497" data-ember-action="498" data-channel-link="data-channel-link">
        <script id="metamorph-362-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>SKT T1 K vs Najin sword NLB Final<script id="metamorph-362-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      </a><script id="metamorph-361-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      <script id="metamorph-363-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script><script id="metamorph-363-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    </p>
    <p class="info">
      <script id="metamorph-364-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>56,951<script id="metamorph-364-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      viewers on
      <a href="/nicegametv/profile" data-bindattr-499="499" data-ember-action="500">
        <script id="metamorph-365-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>nicegametv<script id="metamorph-365-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the grease monkey code that i'm using to do it

```
var killIt=["Hearthstone: Heroes of Warcraft", "League of Legends", "Minecraft"];
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("boxart");
//runthrough elements killing certain ones
for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) 
    {
        for (j=0;j<killIt.length; j++) 
            {
                if (el[i].getAttribute("original-title")==killIt[j]) 
                    {
                        var ely=el[i].parentNode;
                        ely.parentNode.removeChild(ely);
                    }
            }
    }   
}
```

I tried making it into a normal HTML file and running it with Firefox, everything works. However when i try to actually execute it on twitch it doesn't work at all.

I assume i don't know something about greasemonkey.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8L79ft6z/)

Comment: This looks like the page HTML source, not the real rendered HTML code after all scripts are executed.

Answer (score -1):

I modified your code a bit, and enden up with this:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var killIt=["http://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Minecraft",  "http://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/League%20of%20Legends", "http://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Hearthstone%3A%20Heroes%20of%20Warcraft"];
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName("boxart");
    for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) 
        {
            for (j=0;j<killIt.length; j++) 
                {
                    if (el[i].parentNode.href==killIt[j]) 
                        {
                            el[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
                        }
                }
        }
};
```

I added the `window.onload` function because Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey has a tendency of executing the code before the HTML is completely loaded.

I struggled finding your `original-title` attribute, and decided to go for the `href` instead, which is always there (I also changed the values in the `killIt` array into href's).

At last, I made it so you delete the node for the whole game item on the page (and not just the boxart) if this is what you wanted?